# How to create a table from .txt file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create e dataframe (table with three columns) from a .txt file.

I prepared the txt file so it has the format:

> Car
>
> Audi A4 10000
>
> Audi A6 12000
>
> ....
>
> Bus
>
> VW Transporter 15000
>
> ...
>
> Camper
>
> VW California 20000
>
> ...

This is the whole code:

```
cars = ""
with open("cars.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
    cars = f.read()
print(cars)

def generate_car_table(table):
    table = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['category', 'model','price'])
    return table

cars_table = generate_car_table(cars)
```

I expect a table with three columns - category, which will show whether the vehicle is car/bus/camper, model and price.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Great that you mention the expected output. However, what is your current output with your current code? Maybe then we can see what goes wrong. :)

Comment: I get the following error message: name 'pd' is not defined

Comment: I updated the code in the post so you can see the whole code now :)

Comment: If the error is: **NameError: name 'pd' is not defined**  -  you have to **import pandas as pd** first in order to load and rename the package _Pandas_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update:

Having your comments in mind, I see that I misunderstood your question.
If you're text-file (`cars.txt`) looks like follows:

```
Car
Audi A4         10000
Audi A6         12000

Bus
VW Transporter  15000

Camper
VW California   20000
```

so that after every `category` a line break is made and between the `model` and the `price` is a tab, you could run the following code:

```py
# Read the file 
data = pd.read_csv('cars.txt', names=['Model','Price','Category'], sep='\t')

# Transform the unstructured data
data.loc[(data['Price'].isnull() == True), 'Category'] = data['Model']
data['Category'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
data.dropna(axis=0, subset=['Price'], inplace = True)

# Clean the dataframe
data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
data = data[['Category', 'Model', 'Price']]
print(data)
```

This does result in the following table:

```py
  Category           Model    Price
0      Car         Audi A4  10000.0
1      Car         Audi A6  12000.0
2      Bus  VW Transporter  15000.0
3   Camper   VW California  20000.0
```

---

#### Old Answer:

Your text-file needs a fixed structure (for example all values are separated by a tabulate or a line break).
Then you can use the `pd.read_csv` method and define the separator by hand with `pd.read_csv('yourFileName', sep='yourseperator')`.

Tabs are `\t` and line breaks `\n`, for example.

The following `cars.txt` ([link](https://file.io/N4bTtm)) for example is structured using tabs and can be read with:

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv('cars.txt', sep = '\t')
```

Comment: Yes, I know about this option, but in case the file does not have a fixed structure, is there a way to create a table without preparing the .txt file and bringing it into a fixed structure.

Comment: Your text-file needs to have some kind of structure in order to be parsed into a dataframe.

If this is not possible, it is technically achievable to load the whole file as a single string and divide it afterwards into columns (using, for example, regular expressions).
This would be very complicated and inefficient - you should try to format the data beforehand somehow.

Comment: Ok, I see! I thought there is an option though, but obviously there is not :D Thank you for the answer!

Comment: And what if I have 2 delimiters? For example, my category (car,bus,camper) have a double newline delimiter from the objects in this category, but the objects are separated by only 1 newline and the price is delimited by a tab like this:
'Car\n\nAudi A4\t10000\nAudi A6\t12000\n\nBus\nVW Transporter\t15000\n\nCamper\nVW\tCalifornia 20000\n' .
How can I create the three columns in this case, because I can add only 1 delimiter while reading and I get an error message: [Errno 2] File b'...... does not exist:.....

Comment: I have revised the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely far easier to create a table from a CSV file than from a text file, as it will make the job of parsing much easier, and also provide the benefit of being easily viewed in table format in spreadsheet applications such as Excel.

You create the file so that it looks something like this

```
category,model,price
Car,Audi A4,10000
Car,Audi A6,12000
...
```

And then use the `csv` package to easily read/write the data into tabular formats